# Why won't my AngularJS service expose it's function?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-service

My service is:

```
myApp.service 'userService', [
  '$http'
  '$q'
  '$rootScope'
  '$location'
  ($http, $q, $rootScope, $location) ->
    deferred = $q.defer()

    @initialized = deferred.promise

    @user =
      access: false

    @isAuthenticated = ->
      @user =
        first_name: 'Shamoon'
        last_name: 'Siddiqui'
        email: 'ssiddiqui@liquidnet.com'
        access: 'institution'

      deferred.resolve()
]
```

And I'm loading it in a `.run` as follows:

```
myApp.run [
  '$rootScope'
  'userService'
  ($rootScope, userService) ->

    userService.isAuthenticated().then (response) ->
      if response.data.user
        $rootScope.$broadcast 'login', response.data
      else
        userService.logout()
]
```

But firebug is telling me:

```
TypeError: userService.isAuthenticated is not a function
    return userService.isAuthenticated().then(function(response) {
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you need something like: `@isAuthenticated = () -> ...` ? Also, you don't seem to be returning a promise.

Comment: That is equivalent to: `@isAuthenticated = ->`. That's fine if I don't return a promise. It should error about that. Not saying that the `isAuthenticated` isn't a function

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the real JS (or post it for us to take a look at). I am not really familiar with CoffeeScript/TypeScript :(

Comment: Not familiar with the *Script you're using. But does it return anything? A service needs a return object of public methods/variables.

Comment: @gonzofish: the factory() method expects the function to return an object. But the service() method takes a constructor function as argument. And a constructor doesn't return an object.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't even notice the service! Could you post the JS output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is compiled to this:

```
return this.isAuthenticated = function() {
 ...
```

That means that `userService` is in fact the `isAuthenticated` function.
Just add a `return` statement at the end of the `userService` function.